Problems with Next.js and Docker input image
I'm posting here because I've been struggling with an issue for a while now.
I'm trying to dockerize a Next.js application, and I have a feature that allows users to upload images via a form. The form works, but when I add an image, it is not recognized by Next.js, even though it is present in /app/public.
Does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you in advance.
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    container_name: bertin-db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=*****
      - POSTGRES_USER=*****
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*****
    networks:
      - bertin
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

  front:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./public:/app/public
      - ./prisma/seeding/seeding-user.mjs:/app/prisma/seeding/seeding-user.mjs
      - ./prisma/seeding/seeding-vehicule.mjs:/app/prisma/seeding/seeding-vehicule.mjs
    networks:
      - bertin

networks:
  bertin:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db-data:

---------------------------


FROM node:lts-buster-slim AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev ca-certificates -y
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

FROM base as build
RUN export NODE_ENV=production
RUN yarn

COPY . .

RUN yarn prisma generate
RUN yarn build

FROM base as prod-build

RUN yarn install --production
COPY prisma prisma
RUN yarn prisma generate
RUN cp -R node_modules prod_node_modules

FROM base as prod
COPY --from=prod-build /app/prod_node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY --from=build  /app/.next /app/.next
COPY --from=build  /app/public /app/public
COPY --from=build  /app/prisma /app/prisma
COPY --from=build /app/next.config.mjs /app/next.config.mjs

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]

I searched everywhere but found nothing on this subject
